# Delete records from table by keeping the first 100 records

Tags: sql-server

I want to keep the latest 100 records (lastmodifiedtime is a datetime column)and delete the remaining records. 
I am struggling to get the query for the purpose.

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT TOP 100 *
 FROM [mytable]
 ORDER BY LastModifiedTime desc
 )
  DELETE FROM CTE
```

- This query deletes the first 100 records. I actually wanted to keep them.

Comment: you don't need to use a cte for that, see my answer.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows you how to do it the way you were trying.  Tanner's way is a littler easier, but I thought it might be nice to show you how to solve it that way as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query like this will give you the id's of the latest 100 records:

```
SELECT TOP 100 ID
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
ORDER BY lastmodifiedtime DESC
```

So all you have to do is excluded these id's from your delete:

```
DELETE FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
WHERE ID NOT IN 
      (SELECT TOP 100 Id
       FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
       ORDER BY lastmodifiedtime DESC)
```

Just replace `ID` with your identifying field and `[YOUR_TABLE]` with your table name.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the CTE idea, you could leverage the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastModifiedTime DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM [mytable]
)
DELETE FROM cte
    WHERE RowNum > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

--assuming ean is a unique key column in x1

```
with o1 as (select Top 100 ean from x1 order by DATE1)
 delete from x1 where ean not in (select ean from o1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has used offset yet, so I thought I'd put in my two cents!

```
; WITH cte_Offset (
SELECT myTableID
  FROM [myTable]
 ORDER BY LastModifiedTime Desc
OFFSET 100 ROWS )

DELETE 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE myTableID IN (SELECT myTableID FROM cte_Offset)
```